# Dropdownlist showing default value but cannot be popped down

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have dropdownlist which shows default value, when we click the grid view.
At the same time, the dropdown list is not populationg to update values.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM COMPANY";
                DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
                dtt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                DropDownList ddlCompanyName = new DropDownList();
                String compidd = ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue;
                ddlCompanyName.DataSource = dtt;
                ddlCompanyName.DataTextField = "COMPANYNAME";
                ddlCompanyName.DataValueField = "COMPANYID";
                ddlCompanyName.DataBind();
                ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue = compidd;
```

> Please help me to populate dropdownlist with default value(compidd) at first place.

Comment: You're creating a new DropDownList every time, you should select the one in the webpage or form instead..

Comment: i have to add from webpage

Answer (score 0):

If the dropdownlist is already existing in your form then clear the existing items and then assign new datasource but avoid assigning a new instance to it. You can clear items with

```
ddlCompanyNames.Items.Clear();
```

If you have to create a dropdown on the fly due to some requirement, then don't forget to add the newly created dropdown to the form/panel.